# How to split vertices by vertex color

Tags: vertices, vertex-colors

I'm using vertex colors, since that's what my minimal game engine understands, but it only understands them on a per-triangle basis, and cannot interpolate across a triangle.  Blender internally seems to store vertex colors per-face, but when exporting to OBJ or PLY, it seems to merge vertices with their colors.

I don't see any option to make OBJ export with duplicated vertices for different colors, and I don't see any way to make it export the vertex colors as a `vc` flag instead of `v`.

Also, PLYs don't seem much better.

I have an idea for a work-around.  Is there any way to duplicate vertices in-place, so there is a unique vertex per color?

[image: Donut with colors]
[image: wish.com donut]

Answer (score 0):

This was far simpler than I expected.  I just have to select all in edit mode, then `Mesh > Split (Alt M) > Faces by Edge`

Then when exporting it exports each each vertex uniquely.